# Patate vs pomme de terre (pour "potato-shaped object" en maths)

Tags: usage, registre-familier, synonymes, science

Pourquoi le mot *patate* est-il considéré familier (au moins en France) ?
Faut-il employer le mot pomme de terre plutôt ?

Par exemple dans des livres (maths, physique, mécanique, etc) anglais on rencontre souvent :

> A potato-shaped object

[image]

https://www.continuummechanics.org/deformationgradient.html

[image]

[source](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oRRGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA55&dq=a%20potato%20shaped%20object%20continuum%20mechanics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb5dGAuPjjAhUtyoUKHQS2DuQQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=a%20potato%20shaped%20object%20continuum%20mechanics&f=false)

Peut-on traduire cela de cette façon :

> Un objet en forme de patate

?

Comment: One of my favourite 15 seconds of Lord of the Rings. In English Sam says "taters" and Gollum asks him what those are. "Po-ta-toes!" Here it is **[in French](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9viBi6s2vks)**...

Comment: [Monsieur patate](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Patate_(jouet)) désapprouve cette discrimination :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le terme usuel c'est « [patatoïde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patato%C3%AFde) ». Ça n'a rien de « familier » dans un document scientifique mais c'est clairement informel.

Answer (score 1):

Pourquoi familier ? Tout simplement parce que toute autre dénomination que la savante ( *Solanum tuberosum* ) est : *populaire* ou *vulgaire* (en son sens premier)

Pour les végétaux, plutôt que de dire *vulgaire* on préfèrera : *vernaculaire*. (Mais cela signifie la même chose)

Ainsi sont donc également *pomme de terre* et *patate*

Une *patate* n'est **pas** une *pomme de terre*. Il s'agit d'abord du tubercule d'une autre plante d'une autre famille. (Que je ne connais pas). C'est par analogie que ce mot a été par suite repris pour désigner tout autre tubercule du même genre. (pomme de terre, topinambour, igname...) En conséquence de quoi... dans les régions où poussent toutes ces sortes de plantes... si tu veux des pommes de terres et pas des topinambours... oui, il vaudra mieux utiliser : *pommes de terre!* ;)

Tant que seule la forme est concernée alors... oui! Le terme générique de *patate* est le mieux adapté. Ainsi en maths quand... tu dois pour la première fois dessiner une ellipse ou... en physique... la première fois que tu bobineras un solénoïde.
Comme observé dans une autre contribution... on pourra entendre *patatoïdal* moi j'aimais mieux le *patatoïde de révolution*.

Comment: Sauf que le patatoïde de révolution c'est un patatoïde particulier, de l'espace…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : de l'espace ? Hmmm... rassure-moi... même réduit à une seule dimension on est toujours bien dedans... hein ? Tu veux peut-être dire de l'espace à 3 D ? Pourquoi pas ! Mais alors 2D spatiales + le temps... ça le fait aussi donc... Et donc ? Nulle raison de chercher ici une sorte de formalisme puisque 1/  formellement... ça le fait très bien 2/ puisque mon j'*aimais* marquait son absence... et l'annonce d'un private joke. Mais peut-être en 68 dessinais-tu des patatoïdes... bourgeois. ;)

Comment: De l'espace n'était qu'une remarque. Mais soit, je veux bien faire des révolutions dans le temps (j'avoue que j'ai du mal à voir l’intérêt, peut-être que ça fait des jolies vidéos?), ou des anneaux dans le plan (euclidien à 2 dimensions, ou pas…), mais y a-t-il encore un intérêt à parler de patatoïdes ? En ce qui concerne 68, peut-être que mes futurs atomes en formaient un, à défaut d'en dessiner.